# OutOfMemory Exception using backgroundworker on C# : works fine without backgroundworker

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, backgroundworker

I'm writing a project in C# and I've run into a problem using backgroundworker to keep my form responsive whilst an expensive process runs. When I use the bgw method, I get an OutOfMemory exception. However, if I just run my ExpensiveMethod() directly without using bgw then I don't have any issues. Any ideas? I really want to be able to implement a progress bar whilst this method runs (its quite a time consuming process and the user needs to know how long is left). I am fairly new to C# and definitely a novice with threading.

Here is how I'm implementing my bgw and ExpensiveMethod():

```
 private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     myProgressBar.Visible = true;
     bgw.RunWorkerAsync();           
 }


 private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     ExpensiveMethod();
 }

private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 { 
     myProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
 }

 private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 {       
     myProgressBar.Visible = false;
 }


private void ExpensiveMethod()
{
    // do a big calculation and call this every so often:
    bgw.ReportProgress((int)percentComplete);

}
```

This method, however, works fine with no memory exceptions, but obviously locks up the form whilst it runs:

```
private void btnGoThatWorks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExpensiveMethod();            
}
```

Any ideas? I am on Windows7 32-bit.

Comment: How do we get from `bgw` to `bgwAntenna` ? What's the platform here? How/when are the events subscribed to?

Comment: Make sure you are passing integer value in bgwAntenna.ReportProgress(); to raise the ProgressChanged event of the background worker.

Comment: Not obvious. `ExpensiveMethod()` doesn't call `UpdateSomeFieldsOnForm()`, so maybe the memory leak is inside this latter method?

Comment: ignore the reference to bgwAntenna, that was just a typo when changing my names to something generic. I can remove the UpdateSomeFieldsOnForm() method and the problem remains. I'm definitely passing an (int) into the reportprogress method.

Comment: We really need to see what ExpensiveMethod() is in order to help you.  The code you posted doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: Hmm. @LarsTech that is both helpful and unhelpful. Helpful because it helps me narrow down the problem but unhelpful because I can't share the details of ExpensiveMethod() here. Doh. :-(

Comment: My intent wasn't to be unhelpful.  But you have an OutOfMemoryException, but you didn't post any code that reproduces the error.  We can't even guess at the problem.  Manipulating images?  Accessing controls?

Comment: I know you weren't meaning to be unhelpful! (I uprated your comment). he ExpensiveMethod involves crunching a lot of large arrays of numbers together. Now that I know my bgw implementation is not to blame I can try to narrow it down further. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer was that I was calling ***bgw.ReportProgress((int)percentComplete);*** far too often --- changing the code so it only reports every few percent seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: I don't think this is the root cause of the OutOfMemoryException, reporting progress frequently can harm the performance of your program, but it will not result in cumulative memory consumption. OutOfMemoryException is very interesting... most of the time I can find that it is caused by an unintended recursive method call...and then I can happily fix it.